# request header undefined - nodejs SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

when using `req.headers.host` in Express.js and Nodejs 6 on an SSL enabled server im getting **undefined header** error.

**My Code:**

```
if(req.headers.host.indexOf('domain.com')>-1){
  ......
}
```

**Error what im getting:**

```
www-0 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Comment: What's the context of this? What do you see when you console.log the object `req.headers`?

Comment: When i do `console.log` i get `undefined`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a request you're receiving in Express. What does `req` look like?

Comment: A client can always choose to not send that header with a request.

Comment: @robertklep then how do we get the host name for each request?? do we have any alternate solution for this?

Comment: @FahidMohammad I'm saying that you should always check to see if that header exists and not assume that it will. You can always decide to reject requests that don't have such a header if you like.

Comment: @robertklep i understood what you meant, but my application has to have an option to check the host name before i allow the user to access the application. it is part of localization redirection.

Comment: @FahidMohammad in that case you could use something like this: `if (! req.headers.host) return res.sendStatus(400)`. If you run into any clients that don't send a `Host` header (like HTTP scanners or some bots), you just reject the request.

Answer (score 1):

Express's documentation has a section on [req.hostname](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname).

Try doing something like this:

```
if (req.hostname === 'domain.com') {
    ..........
}
```

Inside of an Express app.js file you can do this, which worked for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!' + ' Hostname is ' + req.hostname);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: Hi, `req.hostname: undefined` this is what im getting for many request.

Comment: I'm about to update my answer to give you better context.

Comment: @FahidMohammad as I've said before: you shouldn't expect `req.hostname` (or `req.headers.host`) to always be defined.